# TeXstudio 2.10.4 and moderncv makecvfooter not found

Tags: latex

With the last version of TeXStudio (and moderncv) the command makecvfooter that I use to add an extra line on the footer is not recognized (error \makecvfooter undefined. \renewcommand*{\makecvfooter} ). How can I solve ?

My Code:

```
\makeatletter
% defines one's skype (optional)
% usage: \skype{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyfoot[c]{%
  \parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
    \centering%
    \color{color2}\addressfont%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
      \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}{}{\addtofooter{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{skype_gray}~\@skype}}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
    }}}%
 \pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: Hi Can you please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: I've added a snippet.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with TeXStudio. But with the underlying (La)TeX installation. Namely the moderncv class.
In moderncv 2.0.0 (released 2015-07-28) your command has a new name:

```
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
}%
```

old was:

```
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
}%
```

Sources:
https://answers.launchpad.net/moderncv/+question/275714 
https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/moderncvfooti.sty

Comment: As you see in the answer, after changing the command, something else is broked.

Comment: I can only see my answer, nothing which is broken. And the snipped in your question is not a MWE. Without a MWE identifying your problem further is nearly impossible. Follow these instructions http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that to add a "MWE" (Minimal Working Example)

Comment: just write \vspace{-0.8cm} and receive "Undefined control sequence."

Answer (score 1):

As a fix I also needed to change:

```
\makeletterfooter
```

to

```
\makeletterfoot
```

and

```
\renewcommand*{\makeletterfooter}{%
```

to

```
\renewcommand*{\makeletterfoot}{%
```

in files moderncv.cls and moderncvstylecasual.sty to make things work again.